# What do you do to fix verification problem when seting up my Twitter account on Gwibber?

Tags: 12.04, gwibber, twitter

I have been using Gwibber for a while and liked it. I tried adding Twitter and have been stuck on the verifying part of the set up. When I log in using Gwibber and finds my account almost instantly. Is there a fix or update I should know about? Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while, but I remember just starting the whole process over and somehow it worked. I don't have anything more specific than that.

Comment: I've been trying that for a while now and still nothing. It is still stuck in the verifying stage.